# div controls or canvas controls for designing snake and ladder game?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime

I would like to design a snake and ladder game in Windows 8 HTML5 and javascript.I would like to know what is the best approach?

Using DIV only or CANVAS only controls ? or any other type of control ?

Answer (score 0):

Go with the `<canvas>`element. This is a really good HTML5 game development resource: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/gaming